# incompatible type erros in android studio

Tags: java, android

I received an error that says:

> Incompatible Types.
>
> Required: android.support.v4.app.Fragment
>
> Found: com.ortegapatriciaa.enventer._7_ViewClient_UpcomingEvents"

Here is my code:

#### PageAdapter.java

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                _7_ViewClient_UpcomingEvents tab1 = new _7_ViewClient_UpcomingEvents();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                _7_ViewClient_MyEvents tab2 = new _7_ViewClient_MyEvents();
                return tab2;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

#### _7_ViewClient_UpcomingEvents.java

```
public class _7_ViewClient_UpcomingEvents {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_7_view_client_upcoming_events, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method signature says it returns a Fragment. You are not returning a Fragment.

Comment: `_7_ViewClient_UpcomingEvents extends Fragment` make sure to choose appropriate import

Comment: Please show us your imports and sample code of fragment?

Comment: I guess you should extend `_7_ViewClient_UpcomingEvents` from `Fragment` or another class which is extended from `Framgent`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your classes should look like :

`public class _7_ViewClient_UpcomingEvents extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

`_7_ViewClient_MyEvents extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Both the classes should be subclasses `Fragment`

Also, I would recommend to follow a better naming convention.